# (python) Passing array into function with conditions using for each in array

Tags: python, arrays, function

I am struggling to pass an array into a defined function that has conditions.

```
def my_function(input):
    if input<=45:
        A=-(1/15)*input - 21

    else:
        A=(1/46)*(input-45) - 24
    return A
A = arange(1,30,1)
B = my_function(A)
```

I get an error that says I need to use a.all() or a.any(). What I want is to input each value into the function, go through the conditions, and create a new array that holds the `return A` from my_function (called B). How can I do this?

Comment: is `arange`, `range`? Also errors don't tell you what to do. Lastly, how can you multiple say `[1,2,3]` into `2`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can map you function over needed sequence using basic loop, where on each iteration the loop will populate the output with needed values, as in:

```
def my_function(input):
    ret = 0
    if input<=45:
        ret = -(1/15)*input - 21
    else:
        ret = (1/46)*(input-45) - 24
    return ret

result = [] # Will store the processed values here

for i in range(1,30):
    result.append(my_function(i))

# Now result is populated with needed values
```

Note, I assumed, you misspelled `range` function.